# git delta compression and its uses

Tags: git, github, compression, gitlab

When I executed `git push`, it displayed following output

```
Counting objects: 214, done.                               
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.                   
Compressing objects: 100% (213/213), done.                 
Writing objects:  26% (57/214), 27.44 MiB | 60.00 KiB/s
```

According to this it is clear that Git uses delta compression method. How does delta compression work ? can it be used for other applications as well ? If yes, please suggest such applications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/1256452 (but no details there either); more details at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/1256452. This code is heavily customized for Git: you could extract it and try to use it elsewhere but you would probably be better off using libxdiff.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go into the details of the algorithms, but you can find useful information in the [manual CH 10](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484013/5784831).

Asking google, I also found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_delta_compression)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, Links provided in answer were helpful. It gave me an overview of `Delta Compression` and `packfiles`. But didn't gave me a clear idea of how it works as mentioned in the question.

Comment: But what would you expect? A tutorial? I think this is impossible here... ;-)