# Git: Strange Behavior Pushing Local Branch to Remote Master?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Git for version control and have a remote repository on Github and a local master on my machine.  The file I'm changing is `Toxic Comment Classification.ipynb`.

I make some modification to the file.  Running `git status` shows:

```
modified:   Toxic Comment Classification.ipynb
```

Then I run:

`git branch develop`

`git checkout develop`

Now running `git status` tells me I'm on the local `develop` branch and I have changes to the `Toxic Comment Classification.ipynb` file.

Now I run:

`git add -u`

`git commit -m "checkpoint"`

and I get back:

```
[develop ef9250e] checkpoint
1 file changed, 116 insertions(+), 99 deletions(-)
```

All seems good.  Now I want to push this local branch (`develop`) to my remote master branch:

```
git push origin master
```

and I get back:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

which is not what I expected / wanted.  I can successfully push to `origin/develop`, however.

1) What am I doing incorrectly here?  I'd expect to see the changes I made on my `develop` branch reflected in `origin/master`...

Finally, I try to get around this all by checking out my local `master` branch and merging in my local `develop` branch.  I then run:

```
git push origin master
```

and get back:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/bclayman/ToxicCommentTextClassification.git
   6de47de..ef9250e  master -> master
```

2) Shouldn't this approach also work?  Its output makes me think nothing has been updated and looking on Github doesn't show any recent update...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the step where you are trying to push `develop` directly to `master`.  Why would you even think to do that?  Note that with regard to your observations, Git will typically allow you to change branches with a dirty working directory, provided that switching to another branch would not result in conflicts with the working directory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just trying to understand what's possible / get a better understanding of Git.  Any thoughts on why checking out master, merging in the `develop` branch and pushing to master seems to result in no change?

Comment: You didn't do this.  You tried to push a different branch directly to the remote `master` branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm referring to the second question (the one where I check out my local master, merge in local develop branch, and push to the remote master at origin/master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push `develop` to `master`, the [syntax would be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13897766/6309):

```
git push origin develop:master
```

The **[push statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484013/6309)** you see in your second command (push to `master` after merge) reflects what has been pushed: nothing.
Nothing because you *already* pushed it to `origin/develop`.
So your second push was just a fast-forward for `master`: `origin/master` adjusted its HEAD to the one of `origin/develop`.

```
x   (HEAD, master, origin/master)
 \
  y (develop, origin/develop)

git merge develop

x   (origin/master)
 \
  y (HEAD, master, develop, origin/develop)

git push

x--y (HEAD, master, origin/master, develop, origin/develop)
```

Comment: Very helpful.  Shouldn't I be able to push to `origin/develop` from my local `develop`, switch to my local `master` branch, merge in my local `develop` branch, and then finally push to `origin/master`?  I would have thought there *would* be changes to my remote `master` in that case.  Why does having pushed to `origin/develop` matter here?

Comment: "Shouldn't I be able to push to origin/develop from my local develop, switch to my local master branch, merge in my local develop branch, and then finally push to origin/master?" That is precisely what the diagrams show.

Comment: " I would have thought there would be changes to my remote master in that case.": there are change: before, `origin/master` referenced `x`, not it references `y`.

Comment: " Why does having pushed to `origin/develop` matters here?" because your local merge fast-forwarded master to develop, which was already pushed. Pushing master pushed no new local commits (that was not *already* pushed).

Answer (score 1):

> *Now I want to push this local branch (develop) to my remote master branch: `git push origin master` and I get back: `Everything up-to-date`*

`git push` is `git push <remote> <refspec>`. `refspec` is not simply what branch to push to (the destination), it's also where to push from (the source). From the [`git-push` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)...

> <refspec>...
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source object <src>, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref <dst>.

The important bit is...

> Otherwise, missing :<dst> means to update the same ref as the <src>.

So `git push origin master` is really `git push master:master`. Nothing has changed on `master` so everything is up to date.

To push `develop` to the remote master its `git push develop:master`.

While you *can* do this, it is not recommend as part of a normal workflow. It will greatly confuse things to have your local repository diverge from the remote.