# GitHub exports too many objects despite .gitignore

Tags: git, github

Every time I push [this repository](https://github.com/antoinecomp/moodbot) I feel that it imports too many objects:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 31708, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23964/23964), ...
```

It has 31708 obects when I think I wrote at most a fifty.
However, I had an idea that everything that was not necessary:

Here is the `.gitignore`:

```
# Environment
MyFlaskAppEnv/*
MyFlaskAppEnv/

# Under Construction
run_app.py
run_rasa_server.py

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]

# Distribution / packaging
bin/
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
```

So where do these `objects` come from ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. `git push` transfers commits; it has nothing to do with your `.gitignore` file. "Fortnight" means two weeks; what is "*I wrote at least a fortnight*" supposed to mean?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking question not clear

Comment: @melpomene okay, I thought that the push would ignore the things added in the `.gitignore`. So I'm not sure what these `objects` are I thought it was the files

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 2):

[Read this article on Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) - Git basically tracks all file diffs, commits, and file groupings as separate `objects` in order to understand the state of your repository and the synchronization steps it needs to apply when merging or pushing one repository branch to another.

Each `object` doesn't necessarily correspond 1:1 to a single file - depending on the steps you took on your local branch, Git may store several file objects, tree objects, and commit objects for each operation you performed.

[Here's another good reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484013/866021).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So each time I do `git add .` I create kind of file diffs, commits, and file groupings ? That seems so much, sometimes I only modify a line

Comment: Yes, that's the way Git is built - all of the `objects` it generates helps it keep track of all the operations and changes you do in your commits.