# How can I repress the output of `git-count-objects` when invoking `git-push`?

Tags: git, output, git-push, verbosity

I consider the output of [`git-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to be quite verbose:

```
$ git push 
Enumerating objects: 36, done.
Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 2.45 KiB | 1.23 MiB/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (19/19), completed with 8 local objects.
To github.com:DataBiosphere/azul.git
 + 541326b5...69385318 issues/noah-aviel-dove/3372-implicit-source-filter-circumvented -> issues/noah-aviel-dove/3372-implicit-source-filter-circumvented
```

The only parts of this output I find interesting or useful are:

- The name of the remote repository to which I'm pushing
- The name of the remote branch
- The name of the local branch
- (Not included in the example above) any error messages or warnings

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21484013/1530508), the rest of the output comes from [`git-count-objects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-count-objects).

I consider this extra output to be a distracting and obstructive waste of screen space.
I am looking for a way to change the behavior of `git-push` that accomplishes two things:

1. Suppress or reduce the output from `git-count-objects`
2. Do **not** supress the elements of the output that I do find useful (all of the bullet points listed above).

The `--quiet` flag fails my second criterion. Is there another way to exert finer control over the output of `git-push`?

Answer (score 0):

My working solution to is alias `git-push` to a bash script that runs:

```
git push --dry-run $@ && git push --quiet $@;
```

Since the statistics on the sent objects are not printed when the objects are not actually sent. This produces the output:

```
$ git push
To github.com:DataBiosphere/azul.git
   e324c486..9990e272  issues/noah-aviel-dove/3372-implicit-source-filter-circumvented -> issues/noah-aviel-dove/3372-implicit-source-filter-circumvented
```

Which is ideal. However, the double invocation of `git-push` introduces a small but noticeable amount of latency. There may exist a superior solution that avoids this.

Comment: Did you experiment with `|` or `while read` to clear the default `git push` output?

Comment: @fluffy I considered that approach but considered it to be fragile since I wasn't confident that there might be other output formats I hasn't yet observed. I'm generally very cautious when it comes to piping from programs whose output isn't intended to be parsed programmatically. Although if you have a working example of this approach, I'd be curious to see it.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately no. I don't see anything really annoying in the `git push` output -- at least it clearly indicates that something is going. However, I haven't check your double-command approach, but doesn't it suppress from-remote messages too?