# How to show for a git repo number of objects, reused, delta stats?

Tags: git

Web search finds only what stats mean e.g. [When I do "git push", what do the statistics mean? (Total, delta, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476167/when-i-do-git-push-what-do-the-statistics-mean-total-delta-etc) and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-count-objects "This counts the number of unpacked object files", which gives:

```
~/Downloads/1$ git count-objects
0 objects, 0 kilobytes
```

When I clone, pack repo the output contains counts:

```
~/Downloads/kernel-mainline$ nice -n 19 git gc --aggressive 
Enumerating objects: 8481144, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8481144/8481144), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8430040/8430040), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8481144/8481144), done.
Total 8481144 (delta 7068797), reused 1223897 (delta 0)
Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 1060199, done.
Writing out commit graph in 4 passes: 100% (4240788/4240788), done
```

What is the easiest way to reproduce output of counts of objects, reused, delta in a local repo?
I've tried cloning from folder to folder, but output just `Cloning into bare repository ... done.`