# Git distributed revision control and filetypes

Tags: git, version-control, file-type

Can Git be used for versioning projects that contain Solidworks files, or Autodesk Inventor files ? My question may not present a concrete problem but I am interesed can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidworks has its own system (workgroup PDM) its made for that. You can use git but Git is not really good for big files. Its better for small files which contains Text.

But the best way is to find it and find it out and make some tests.

Comment: Unlike many old version control systems, Git handles binary files as well as pure text. For the delta algorithm, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689844/what-is-git-actually-doing-when-it-says-it-is-resolving-deltas