# unable to push commits to my git repository

Tags: git

pushing to my git respository stalls at that point, what could be the issue? Kindly help.
Here is my log after I git add and commit my changes.After git pushing to my master branch,the push stalls after compressing the ojects.

```
(virtual) david@david-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/Blog$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   nimo/templates/about.html
modified:   nimo/templates/base.html
modified:   nimo/templates/navbar.html
modified:   static/css/base.css
new file:   static/images/dance.png
new file:   static/images/music.jpg
new file:   static/images/pic1.jpg
new file:   static/images/pic2.jpg
new file:   static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js
new file:   static/js/scripts.js

(virtual) david@david-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/Blog$ git add .
(virtual) david@david-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/Blog$ git commit -m     "comments"
[master 7fd6f10] comments
10 files changed, 10442 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
create mode 100644 static/images/dance.png
create mode 100644 static/images/music.jpg
create mode 100644 static/images/pic1.jpg
create mode 100644 static/images/pic2.jpg
create mode 100644 static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js
create mode 100644 static/js/scripts.js
(virtual) david@david-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK:~/Blog$ git push origin     master
Username for 'https://github.com': DavidNganga
Password for 'https://DavidNganga@github.com': 
Counting objects: 286, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (222/222), done.
Writing objects: 100% (286/286), 412.07 MiB | 53.28 MiB/s, done.
Total 286 (delta 144), reused 112 (delta 50)
```

Also, what does delta stand for?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689844/what-is-git-actually-doing-when-it-says-it-is-resolving-deltas) for an explanation of delta compression. Tip: Try `git push origin master --verbose` to gain more information.

Comment: Add `GIT_TRACE=1` before the command to see the debug information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few reasons:

1. You are trying to push large files

   ```
   Writing objects: 100% (286/286), 412.07 MiB | 53.28 MiB/s, done.
   ```

   Github block push of large files.
2. Debug the process by adding `GIT TRACE=1` before the command

[image]

Comment: GIT TRACE=1 worked , the problem was the large files i was trying to push

Comment: Cool, glad to help, Can u please be kind enough to accept the answer since it solved your problem.Appricated